# 'For (his) betrayal, the general was simply demoted a little in rank.' vs. 'For the general's betrayal he was simply demoted a little in rank.'

Tags: pronouns, prepositional-phrases, personal-pronouns

I am trying to translate a sentence into English. Here is what I have got:

1. For **the general's betrayal, he** was simply demoted a little in rank.
2. For **his betrayal, the general** was simply demoted a little in rank.
3. For **betrayal, the general** was simply demoted a little in rank.

My question is, is the probability of the interpretation that it was the general who was demoted the same in all the three sentences?

What if the previous context for each of these three was: '**I am sorry for Hopkins.**'?

Comment: They all "syntactically valid", but "fronting" the adverbial "reason" clause without a possessive is a bit odd in #3. Obviously if you *didn't* front it, you wouldn't use *...for **the general's** betrayal,* because he'll already have been identified: *The general was simply demoted a little in rank **for [his] betrayal***. In that sequence (which is effectively the *default* in English, without "fronting") it's optional whether to include the possessive pronoun. None of this affects the meaning, only the idiomacy.

Comment: Compare *For [his] dishonesty, the new worker was sacked* (not very natural in most contexts) and the perfectly natural utterance *The new worker was sacked for dishonesty* (where ***his** dishonesty* is valid, but less likely).

Comment: Wait, are "Hopkins" and "the general" different people? If so, adding "I'm sorry for Hopkins" radically alters the meaning of some of them. I have an answer prepared for this case, but I'm not sure it's true. Voting to close as unclear; please edit to explain.

Comment: *"The general got a small demotion for a big betrayal"*

Comment: @AndyBonner Yes, 'adding "I'm sorry for Hopkins" radically alters the meaning of some of them'. Please give us your perception how.

Comment: Please use the "edit" button to update the question. Comments aren't permanent or "official"; we should put all the necessary information in the question itself. I'm still puzzled—if Hopkins is not the general's name, but is a different person... then why do we feel sorry for Hopkins, if the general is the one who got a demotion? Maybe make it very clear in the question which meaning you *want*, since some of these wordings change who betrayed whom or who got demoted. Also, note the dangers of discussing sentences out of context. In a story, I'm sure we'd be clear already who Hopkins was.

Comment: It's possible that Hopkins was punished a lot for Hopkins' betrayal, and the general was published a little for the general's betrayal. But it's also possible that the general was punished for Hopkins' betrayal, either more or less than Hopkins was, or indeed that both of them were punished for the general's betrayal, and the narrator may have felt that any of these was too much or too little. Normally you'd have context, a knowledge of character, and a sense of how punishment works in this particular society.

Comment: Can I ask who committed the betrayal?  Who betrayed whom? And who is being demoted? Without this information, I don't think a definitive answer is possible here.  We need much more context.  Note also that the "general's betrayal" suggests that the general committed the betrayal. Are you aware of how English uses the possessive? Can you please edit your question and add more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It changes everything to say that the preceding sentence is "I am sorry for Hopkins." In fact, it took me some time to realize that I believe you mean that "Hopkins" and "the general" are different people—perhaps Hopkins did the betraying but the general bore the penalty. In that case, some of these have very different meanings. It's all about pronouns. When we encounter a pronoun, we search around for its antecedent. If we never mentioned Hopkins, the only obvious choice of an antecedent for "he" or "his" is "the general," and all three examples would mean that the general betrayed and was demoted.

But...

> I'm sorry for Hopkins. For the general's betrayal, he was simply demoted a little in rank.

First of all, in this version "he" seems to mean "Hopkins." And the phrase "the general's betrayal" would usually be understood as "the betrayal that the general showed or committed," not "the act of betraying the general." So in this version, the general was traitorous and Hopkins was punished.

> I'm sorry for Hopkins. For his betrayal, the general was simply demoted a little in rank.

In this version, "his" appears to mean "Hopkins'," and now the betrayal belongs to him via this possessive pronoun. So in this version, Hopkins was the traitor and the general was punished.

> I'm sorry for Hopkins. For betrayal, the general was simply demoted a little in rank.

This one frankly doesn't make much sense. This one uses no pronouns, and it's quite clear that the general was both the traitor and the one punished. But what does this have to do with Hopkins?

Comment: I'm sorry for Hopkins (who was made a scapegoat and sent to jail). For betrayal, the general was simply demoted a little in rank.

Comment: @Mamamia Thanks, that at least makes it clear that Hopkins and "the general" are different people. But this is the wrong place for the explanation. We're in a comments section here, and these aren't "official" or permanent. The main question itself should have all the information necessary to answer it. Please use the "Edit" button to add the extra context you gave here. Also, it still doesn't make it totally clear who betrayed whom. Was Hopkins totally innocent? The general betrayed someone?

Answer (score 0):

In all three versions, the natural reading is that the general was demoted.

But when you say, "I am sorry for Hopkins" first, that raises questions about who betrayed whom. Do you mean that Hopkins betrayed the general and then the general was penalized for it? That Hopkins betrayed the general and the general by revealing that he (the general) was the one guilty of some other offense, which he was then peanlized for? That the general betrayed Hopkins? That Hopkins and the general are the same person? Maybe with larger context this is all clear, but with just those two sentences, it's very confusing.